# How conservation of energy looks like in the moving frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation

It is obvious that a car accelerates by converting its chemical energy in the fuel to produce kinetic energy to accelerate itself.
If the energy is lost into friction and heat, the car will slow down.
But from the point of view of the car, it always appears to be stationary, which means its kinetic energy is zero. So what is the thing that the fuel actually does in the car frame?

Answer (score 1):

From the car's point of view, there is a fictitious force, which does work. Therefore, the car sees extra potential energy. You can think of the fictitious force as weak constant gravity. Similar to how you can see gravitational potential energy, in the car's perspective, there is the fictitious force's potential energy.

Edit: Because I didn't actually answer the question. What's happening to the energy in the fuel in the car's perspective is that it's being converted into kinetic energy. The car has to push things backwards in order to move forward. What the car sees is that it's using the fuel in order to push things twice as strong backwards. The reason why the car isn't moving forward in the car's perspective is because momentum isn't necessary conserved because there is a force in the non inertial frame of reference.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're saying the car is using its fuel to fight against the gravitational field which is generated in a non-inertial reference frame?

Comment: You can say so. It's like a rocket being stationary because it's burning fuel to accelerate as much as it's being pulled by earth. From the point of view of someone falling to earth, he would see the rocket is using fuel to accelerate.

Comment: @Habouz What is the connection between the two paragraphs of the answer ? It seems they both are not inter-related with each other.

Comment: The first paragraph creates analogy between the car's point of view and someone standing on earth in order to clear any misconception. The answer is in paragraph 2.

Comment: @Habouz Sorry, it maybe a silly question but can you explain that in the 8th and 9th line of 2nd paragraph, car is pushing what? Also, why with double rate?

Comment: The car is pushing thrust. It's double the "speed" not the rate. In someone standing's frame of reference, he sees the can have momentum p1, and the thrust has momentum -p1 due to momentum conservation. In the car's perspective, the momentum increased because the car sees the thrust being pushed faster.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score -1):

Energy is not invariant across reference frames. From the car's frame you would correctly calculate the car's kinetic energy to be 0. The earth, on the other hand, would have massive kinetic energy.

The fuel does work against the pistons in the engine. The energy is lost in the same places as before.

Comment: I understand you but this would make it seem that the fuel is being used to push the earth backward. This is not true because the energy to push earth backward is far greater than what's in the fuel.

Comment: @Habouz no, that's only when accelerating. You can only talk about energy conservation in an inertial reference frame. At constant velocity there is no "pushing the earth backward"

Answer (score -1):

Let' say there are two earths, on one of those earths a car is accelerating.

Now the car says that the kinetic energy of the earth that the car is not pushing increases by a huge amount, and the kinetic energy of the earth that the the car is pushing increases by the same huge amount plus the energy of the burned fuel. Or it increases by the same huge amount + force * distance.